# R- Conditional calculation based on reference to values in other row

Tags: r, if-statement, reference

I would like to make a reference to a value in the same column on another row. I have one column with start and stop moment. I would like to add a column that indicates if the machine is running or not.

This is how the data looks like:

```
c("", "", "start", "", "", "stop", "", "", "start", "stop", "")
```

The output should look like this:

```
 [1,] ""      ""       
 [2,] ""      ""       
 [3,] "start" "running"
 [4,] ""      "running"
 [5,] ""      "running"
 [6,] "stop"  "running"
 [7,] ""      ""       
 [8,] ""      ""       
 [9,] "start" "running"
[10,] "stop"  "running"
[11,] ""      ""
```

In the second column I would like to do:

- IF same row first column equals start --> running
- ELSE IF previous row first column equals stop --> ""
- ELSE the same value as the previous row for the second column

How can I do this in an elegant way with R?

Thank you very much on beforehand for your input!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cumsum` to check wether there are more "start" values than "stop" values to know if the process is running or not:

```
res <- cbind(myvec, c("", "running")[(cumsum(myvec=="start") > cumsum(myvec=="stop")) + 1])
```

you can add "running" for lines with "stop" afterwards:

```
res[res[, 1]=="stop", 2] <- "running"

res
#      myvec            
# [1,] ""      ""       
# [2,] ""      ""       
# [3,] "start" "running"
# [4,] ""      "running"
# [5,] ""      "running"
# [6,] "stop"  "running"
# [7,] ""      ""       
# [8,] ""      ""       
# [9,] "start" "running"
#[10,] "stop"  "running"
#[11,] ""      ""
```

**data**

```
myvec <- c("", "", "start", "", "", "stop", "", "", "start", "stop", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is not the most elegant way but somehow I think it gives what you want. You can use a `for-loop`

```
x <- c("", "", "start", "", "", "stop", "", "", "start", "stop", "")
flag <- 0
y <- array()

for(i in 1:length(x))
{
  if(flag == 0 & x[i] == "")
  y[i] <- ""
  else if(x[i] == "start" | x[i] == "")
  {
   flag = 1;
   y[i] <- "running"
  } 
  else if(x[i] == "stop")
  {
   y[i] <- "running"
   flag <- 0
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
y
#[1] ""        ""        "running" "running" "running" "running" ""        ""        "running"
#[10] "running" ""
```